# I would like to move my family to a new home but the speech option does not appear

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I have built a new house near Dawnstar and I have all the requirements for asking my family to move but the speech option to ask them does not appear.

What am I doing wrong? By the way, I don't know if this might have something to do with it but I have asked my wife to move once before - might that be the problem?

I am playing on the PS3.

Answer (score 0):

If you have children, you need to have child's beds and containers in the bedroom wing or on the left side of the upstairs room. If you already did this, and it is still not working, try to tell them to move to another home, talk to them at the home they moved to, and there should be an option.